# how do i use the jqx jquery library with mvc4?

Tags: .net, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4

Sorry for the vagueness of the question but it is pretty simple. I'm not sure I'm setting up this jquery library correctly to be used with mvc 4. http://www.jqwidgets.com

None of the demos are working. There are no errors, it simply isn't doing anything. For instance:

```
@section pageScripts
{
    <!-- add the jQuery script -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>    
    <!-- add the jQWidgets framework -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/jqwidgets/jqwidgets/jqxcore.js"></script>
    <!-- add one or more widgets -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/jqwidgets/jqwidgets/jqxbuttons.js"></script>
    <!-- add one of the jQWidgets styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/jqwidgets/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.darkblue.css" type="text/css" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var theme = getTheme();
            var source = '@Model.Friends';
            $('#friendsList').jqxDropDownList({ source: source, selectedIndex: 1, width: '200', height: '25', theme: theme });
        });
    </script>
}

<div id='friendsList'></div>
```

This is the example given from the site, but it doesn't do anything. I've also noticed that none of the controls are popping up in intellisense (VS2012).

I suspect that there is something that needs to be configured in bundles or rendering in _layout.cshtml

I'm really new to this. I haven't been able to fine much of a straight answer on the web. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

There is a help topic which demonstrates how to use the widgets with ASP .NET MVC4 - [asp.net-binding-to-sql-database-mvc4](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/asp.net-integration/asp.net-binding-to-sql-database-mvc4.htm).